# How to efficient use same dataframe for multiple calculations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've this below some small snippet of code

```
val listDF = Seq(ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN)

    val calculateDf = listDF.foldLeft(inputDF)((inpDf, listElement) => {

      val calculatedDf =
        inpDf.doingSomething(listElement, dataDF, secondDF, status)
        .groupByColNames(listOfCols(status))

      calculatedDf
    })
```

Here I'm doing 10 times transformation on same dataframe, and in every transformation its getting bigger exponentially.

May I know the suggestion, is there any other two achieve this in better way ?

I've 500 nodes cluster with 256 gb memory each node. Initial set of data size is aprrox 1tb

Its taking 3+ hours to complete.

Comment: Can you please provide insight as to what you are trying to achieve by that code?  Ideally that list would be used within an "in" clause rather than repeated projections.

Comment: @Chris, doingSomething has different transformations, so cant share here, but there nothing special is happening, just some filter conditions, and simple inner joins for every element in list. You said, list would be used within an "in" clause, can you please share more about this ? I think issue is with using List of elements with foldLeft, becasue everytime data become big and it has to shuffle partitions.

Comment: The fold left is not relevant, you'd have the same problem if you wrote out each of the steps by hand, you keep adding projections, this increases the memory and shuffling considerably as it makes it difficult for spark to optimise them out.  The "in" clause I mentioned is literally SQL in (isin/isInCollection in the dsl).  Something in doingSomething uses that listElement, instead of making that an = test re-write it to use in and isInCollection and don't keep adding projections